# Reading multiple excel files in pyspark/pandas

Tags: python, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a scenario where I need to read excel spreadsheet with multiple sheets inside and process each sheet separately.
The Sheets inside the excel workbook are named something like [sheet1, data1,data2,data3,summary,reference,other_info,old_records]

I need to read only sheets [reference, data1,data2,data3]

I can hardcode the name reference which is static everytime, but the names data1,data2,data3 are not static as there maybe data1 only or data1,data2 or it can be (eg) data1,data2….data(n)

whatever the count of the sheets be, it will remain same across all files (eg - its not allowed to have Data1,Data2 in one file and Data1,Data2,Data3 in the other - Just to clarify the requirement).
I can check the name by using the following code

```
reallall = [key for key in pd.read_excel(path,sheet_name = None) if ('Data') in key]
for n in range(0,len(readall)):
  sheetname = readall[n]
  dfname = df_list[n] – trying to create dynamic dataframe so that we can create separate tables at the end

for s in allsheets:
    sheetname = s
data_df = readfile(path,s,”’Data1!C5’”)  -- function to read excel file into dataframe
df_ref = readreference(path,s,”’Reference!A1’”)
```

df_ref is same for all sheets in a workbook, and the data_df is joined with the reference. (Just adding this as an info – there are some other processing that needs to be done as well, which I have already done)
the above is a sample code to read a particular sheet.

My Problem is:

1. I have Multiple excel files (around 100 files) to read.
2. Matching sheets from all files should be combined together (eg) ‘Data1’ from file1 should be combined with data1 from file2, data1 from file3 … and so on. Similary Data2 from all files should be combined into a separate dataframe (all sheets have same columns)
3. Separate delta tables should be created for each tab (eg) table for Data1 should be something like Customers_Data1, Table for Data2 should be Customers_Data2 and so on.
   Any help on this please ?
   Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved my Issue through the following code.

```
final_dflist = []
sheet_names = [['Data1','CUSTOMER_DATA1'],['Data2','CUSTOMER_DATA2']]
for shname in sheet_names:
  final_df = spark.createDataFrame([],final_schema)
  print(f'Initializing final df - record count: {final_df.count()}')
  sheetname = shname[0]
  dfname = shname[1]
  print(f'Processing: {sheetname}')
  for file in historic_files:
    fn = file.rsplit('/',1)[-1]
    fpath = '/dbfs' + file
    print(f'Reading file:{fn} -->{sheetname}')
    indx_df = pd.read_excel(fpath,sheet_name = 'Index', skiprows = None)
    
    for index,row in indx_df.iterrows():
      if row[0] == 'Data Item Description':
        row_index = 'A' + str(index+2)
        df_index = read_index(file,'Index',row_index)
        df_index = df_index.selectExpr('`Col 1` as co_1','Col2','Col3','Col4')
    
    df_data = read_data(file,sheetname,'A10')
       
    # Join Data with index here
       
    # Drop null columns from final df   
    df = combine_df.na.drop("all")
    
  exec(f'{dfname} = final_df.select("*")')
  final_dflist.append([dfname,final_df])
  print(f'Data Frame created:{dfname}')  
  print (f'final df - record count: {final_df.count()}')
```

Any suggestions to improve this ?

Comment: What is the purpose of indx_df in the code?

Comment: This is to read the reference sheet, which is same for all worksheets in a workbook.

Comment: So, the data in this reference sheet is same for all the excel files? Correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: in reference sheet the data is same for that particular excel file. So each excel file has its own reference sheet that is valid for data sheets only within that file.